# Mysql JSON_REMOVE Array Key and Value (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, arrays, mariadb, key-value

I have the following JSON in MariaDB/MySQL:

```
[{"uid": 5}, {"uid": 6}, {"uid": 7}]

 user_pst_tb
------------------------------
pst_id | pst_liked_by
--------------------------
1      |[]
-------|----------------
.      |[{"uid": 9}]
-------|----------------
.      |[]
-------|----------------
29     |[]
-------|----------------
30     | [{"uid": 5}, {"uid": 6}, {"uid": 7}]
```

i want to use JSON_REMOVE or any method to remove  `{"uid": 6}`  alone on `pst_id = 30`, but i cannot find how to formulate the path. I thought of this:

```
UPDATE user_pst_tb
    SET `pst_liked_by` = JSON_REMOVE( 
        `pst_liked_by`, JSON_UNQUOTE(
            REPLACE( 
                JSON_SEARCH( `pst_liked_by`, 'one', '6', null, '$**.uid' )
                , '.uid'
                , ''
            )
        ) 
    ) WHERE pst_id = 30;
```

for some reason the MariaDB and MySQL docs does not have such examples. Any help is appreciated.

I have also tried:

```
UPDATE user_pst_tb SET `pst_liked_by`= JSON_REMOVE(`pst_liked_by`, JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_SEARCH(`pst_liked_by`, 'one','{"uid": 6}') )) WHERE `pst_id` = 30;
```

The second query clears all the `JSON` data sadly

**UPDATE 1 (some GOOD NEWS)**
I have tried this

```
 UPDATE user_pst_tb SET `pst_liked_by` = 
      JSON_REMOVE(`pst_liked_by`,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_search(`pst_liked_by`, 
'one', '6'))) WHERE `pst_id` = 30;
```

Somehow working but it leaves some empty `{}` behind.

Example: `[{"uid": 5}, {}, {"uid": 7}]` any idea to remove the empty brackets will be great!!

Comment: Now you're learning why the JSON datatype is such a pain to use. Normalize your tables and things will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but so far the JSON approach for this purpose seems very feasible. Any help is highly apprecuated

Comment: maybe JSON_TABLE helps this JSON structure. but only supports mysql 8.0 or higher...

Comment: [JSON_TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) in MariaDB-10.6+ too, but I'm not sure it helps. `JSON_REMOVE` and [predicates](https://archive.fosdem.org/2021/schedule/event/mariadb_json/attachments/slides/4614/export/events/attachments/mariadb_json/slides/4614/mariadb_json_fosdem2021.pdf) seems the right way, but I haven;t worked out the incantation.

Comment: @rodpold Am using this version: 10.5.13-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: have you seen this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/293864/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-json-array-element-by-value-in-mysql

Comment: Let me try and get back

Comment: @WhatsThePoint, Using your link, I tried this **UPDATE nz_psts_01 SET `pst_liked_by` = JSON_REMOVE( `pst_liked_by` , JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT( JSON_SEARCH( `pst_liked_by` , 'one' , @value ) , CONCAT('$[1]') ) ) ) WHERE `pst_id`=30;** but it clears all the JSON in data

Comment: Please see my UPDATE... There is some GOOD NEWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was assisted by @[ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9)

The final query that worked is:

```
UPDATE nz_psts_01
    SET `pst_liked_by` = JSON_REMOVE(
        `pst_liked_by`, JSON_UNQUOTE(
            REPLACE(
                JSON_SEARCH( `pst_liked_by`, 'one', '6', null, '$**.uid' )
                , '.uid'
                , ''
            )
        )
    ) WHERE pst_id = 29
 and JSON_SEARCH( `pst_liked_by`, 'one', '6', null, '$**.uid' ) is not null ;
```

Hope it can help someone